Low pressure boiler leaks water when I open the valve per instructions
These days I have been a visitor at a family's place. This morning the boiler showed a pressure (according to digital reading) of 0.8bar. The side panel instruction says to increase the pressure up to 1.5bars if it's lower than 1 bar, and it points at which valve to open for this. When I do so it starts leaking clear water on the floor. I use a bucket to collect that water, while I let it run and keep an eye on the pressure gauge but after one minute it remains at 0.8bar. That's when I start feeling uncomfortable so I close it, the gauge still shows 0.8 bars. Hours later, still 0.8 bars. I switch off the boiler for 5 seconds and then on, that's according to instructions if something is anomalous. And it reboots immediately saying the presure is now 1.0 bar. I open the valve again for a minute and same thing happens: leak in a bucket, pressure does not go up. I close it.
On top of this the boiler is loud when it switches on, every few minutes, compared to what I hear in my home for instance. The noise is like a loud ignition and then it goes shut after ~2 seconds. Also the shower gives cold water intermitently when using only hot water, and the heaters don't really heat up, they just get lukewarm even if the temp is set 50 degrees Celsius on the boiler.
Is it weird enough to advise calling a boiler engineer?


Seems likely, but you could improve your question by editing in pictures. Sounds like an over-pressure valve opening at too low of a pressure.

@Ecnerwal Sure can do, let me add pictures

@Ecnerwal I did ask myself if I was opening the right valve: there is only one matching the one in the instruction side panel.

The valve I mention would be the one that is letting water out when you let water in. It's normal to have a valve to release excess pressure so the boiler doesn't turn into a bomb. It's normally supposed to open in the vicinity of 2 bar/30 PSI. Sometimes they fail and require replacement. That may not be the only problem here, based on your description, though.

Good point (and thanks for teaching, I would have guessed the boiler needs a way of dropping excess pressure, but have no clue about the mechanism). Should I try tracking the source of the leak? I see drops running from the black plastic hoses.

Can't hurt to look for the leak so long as you don't abuse anything to make it worse, but it does seem like professional help might be useful to you.

A good repair technician will measure the pressure with a test gauge before replacing any parts. The safety valve may have lost calibration and leaking but it is also possible that the pressure transducer could be bad, and the actual pressure is 2 bar, not 1 bar. The electronic display is only as accurate as the transducer that it is measuring.

OK so it's a combined unit for gas central heating / hot water.
I assume the pressure reading is from the central heating circuit, and 0.8 bar is indeed too low, it's time to add more pressure.
On the central heating circuit, there will be a pressure relief safety valve. Its job is to let out the water in case pressure gets too high, to avoid water boiling in the heat exchanger and a steam explosion. This valve is usually built into the gas heater unit, it's somewhere on the bottom where you took the second picture. It is supposed to be connected to a drain pipe, to avoid spraying water everywhere if it ever has to do its job.
Sometimes it is not connected to a drain, then you have to use a bucket...
Look for something like this, with a knob, usually but not always red:

I think in your case this pressure relief valve is either defective or leaky. This happens, they don't last forever. Sometimes a bit of scale or rust from steel radiators wedges itself into it and it leaks.
So, first locate the valve, and make sure the water you saw leaking does come from this valve. If it comes from somewhere else, then ignore the following and call the boiler engineer.
Now put a bucket under it and turn the red knob repeatedly in both directions, it will spray a lot of water and hopefully whatever was clogging the mechanism will also come out.
Then try to increase the pressure again, see if it leaks.
If it still leaks, it is time to replace it. It should be replaced with a model rated to open up at the same pressure. You can call a professional to do this.

Are you missing a flexible hose in the bottom the boiler?  The hose is usually black rubber covered with a steel braid.  With screw-on couplings at the ends.
The valve should be letting water from your house supply into the pressurised system.  The hose is removable, to prevent any risk that water with corrosion inhibitor could flow back into your fresh water supply if the supply pressure dropped below 1 bar for any reason.
But it sounds like all that's happening is that you open the valve, and fresh water pours out onto the floor.

Does not sound idiot proof, if you have to remember to remove a hose for protection.  I would imagine at least a check valve/back flow preventer.

@crip659 there should be one of those too.  And most people never remove the hose anyway.

The problem description reads more like one valve is opened to fill, and another is opening and letting water out. Unfortunately the provided pictures don't clearly identify or show where the valve being opened and the "faucet" letting water out are.

There is a black hose (without steel braid) that goes into the wall, it comes from a 4 way split (cross) where the water leaks from.

@Learningisamess I'm running out of ideas here. Has the installer left any manuals behind that might explain in more detail?  I'm puzzled as to why a hose would come out of the wall.

Have added a picture of the hose if it can help dissipate some confusion. There are no manuals around from my knowledge

@Learningisamess "Is it weird enough to advise calling a boiler engineer?" At this point, I would say "Yes".

@SimonB okay, I take note. Yesterday I switched the boiler off, pressure was 1.1 bar, this morning I woke up to 1 bar. It's really weird, I am warmly advising my relative to seek a professional inspection! Thanks for the help!
